# ko async validation plugin

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, knockout.js

[UPDATED]

I am not sure how to add a custom (html) message to my async knockout validator.

Below is a simple form. You can see that there is already some isModified and isValid validation in-place, but it is not async. (I am not sure if this complicates or simplifies the solution.)

```
<form 
    method="post" 
    action="Registration()" 
    novalidate 
    data-bind="submit: onRegister">
    <div 
        class="input-wrapper email" 
        data-bind="
            validationOptions: {
                messageTemplate: 'emailCollisionTemplate'
            }, 
            validationElement: EmailAddress, 
            css: { 'validation-success': EmailAddress.isModified() && EmailAddress.isValid() }">
        <input 
            type="email" 
            id="registerModalEmail" 
            data-bind="
                value: EmailAddress, 
                ariaInvalid: EmailAddress" 
                aria-describedby="email-address-error" 
                required />
    </div>
    <div 
        class="validation-error-message" 
        id="email-address-error" 
        data-bind="validationMessage: EmailAddress">
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/html" id="emailCollisionTemplate">
    <span>This email is already registered. Please <a href="myUrl/login?">sign in</a>.
    </span>
</script>
```

And then some js:

```
self.EmailAddress = ko.observable().extend({
    required: {
        params: true,
        message: 'required'
        )
    },
    pattern: {
        params: '@',
        message: 'match'
        )
    },
    validation: {
        async: true,
        validator: function (val, parms, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'myUrl/isEmailAllowed',
                data: { 'EmailAddress': val },
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (results) {
                    if (results) {
                        callback(true);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    callback(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

(isModified and isValid is handled elsewhere, so I have not included it.)

How do I configure the messageTemplate to show? I've looked at examples, but none of them seem to match what I'm doing here. I've put the validationOptions into the data-bind like it seems to say, but that's not working.

I should point out two confounding aspects here:

1. There are other validators on this same field (i.e.required and pattern)
2. There are other fields in this form with validation. (The configuration object says the messageTemplate should be *'id of the script that you want to use for **all** your validation messages'*. I only want it for this one field.)

Comment: It looks like you need to make an entry in ko.validation.rules that includes the ajax call in its `validator` member. The `message` member should be your "This email is already registered" message. I *think* the on-submit is not necessary; the validation will happen on change of the variable.

Comment: Thanks. I've had some forward movement on the async validation, so I've updated the question and code. Now I'm stuck on the message Template.